# How to trace SQL statement from Linq query with Where clause?

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, where-clause, trace

I have Linq statement:

```
context.Files.Where(f => ids.Contains(f.FileId))
```

I'm trying to [trace it with Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) but I don't see this query in the output. If I hover over `Files` and then open `Results View` I see the following command issued:

```
SELECT [t0].[FileId], [t0].[Type], [t0].[Name], ... 
FROM [dbo].[File] AS [to]
```

Basically, I need to find out if the query is optimized and I need hard proof.

Comment: Did that statement **actually** produce that trace? And can you show the whole statement, as what you have there is just an expression that returns a lazily evaluated (but not yet evaluated) query object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to [Deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries), your query on its own will not produce any SQL.

However, If you are in your debugger and you have a statement like

```
var query = context.Files.Where(f => ids.Contains(f.FileId))
```

then

```
query.ToList();
```

will execute your query and hence you should see the generated SQL in Sql Profiler etc.

Alternatively

```
Query.ToString();
```

will not execute the query, but will return the generated SQL statement (but does not show the values of the parameters involved).